# How do I create a self join item when it also belongs to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, self-join

I’m trying to make a self join relation for a model named: Subsystem. In this case a Subsystem represents a java package, class or method. 
I’ve read the rails documentation where I saw I could use it like this:

```
class Subsystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_subsystems, class_name: "Subsystem",
                          foreign_key: "parent_id"

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Subsystem"
end
```

I also looked at a couple examples where in most cases the “create part” is not described.
My problem is that i’m looking for the best way to create the subsystems, because:
The Subsystem model also belongs to a Project. 
Right now I create subsystems like:

```
project.subsystems.create(params)
```

I hope this image make’s it better to understand. A project, can have 0 to multpiple subsystems, and every subsystem can also have 0 to multiple subsystems.

[Subsystems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JjLM.png)

I’ve seen examples of making a self join, where people created the item relation with build, but I’m not sure how to combine that with my existing create: project.subsystems.create.

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you have a `has_many` relation, Rails will automatically provide you with a method `build_#{association}` or in your case `build_child_subsystems`

Comment: @Kkulikovskis Thanks for your answer! I will have a look at the build association method to find out how i can combine it with my current way of creating the subsystems and set the parent_id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you created your self join association is spot on.

If you want to create a subsystem that belongs to a project you can do `project.subsystems.create(...)` and if you want to create a subsystem belonging to a subsystem you can do `subsystem.child_subsystems.create(..)`. You effectively call the name of the association defined in the model (pluralised for has many associations).

The difference between build and create methods is that build effectively calls `new` whereas create calls `new` and `save`. When you create or build instances associated with other instances as defined in their models, the returned objects will contain the foreign keys of the records they are built or created from.